# OneDrive IOS SDK, Error : Sorry, but we are having trouble signing in, its bad Request

Tags: ios, ms-office, onedrive

I am using One drive IOS SDK. I have created an app id. its working done but when I login one drive from app/own app, its Shown me this Message:

> Sorry, but we are having trouble signing in, its bad Request.

I used the github link : https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-ios for OneDrive Application.

Firstly, I add the OneDrive SDK pod to my project. then, add this function to app delegate,

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { // Override point for customization after application launch.

[ODClient setMicrosoftAccountAppId:@" - - - - " scopes:@[@"onedrive.appfolder"] ];

return YES;
```

}

and when i run this app to my device, then i found this error.

> We're unable to complete your request
>   Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.

Additional technical information:

> AADSTS5 : Reply addess'um:ietf:wg...' specified by the request is not a valid URL. Allowed schemes: 'http,https'

Answer (score 1):

@Satyam

can you please share your code, so I can get better idea.

**Here You go :**
Code is in swift but you can easily convert into objective C

**Scopes :** offline_access, onedrive.readonly,onedrive.readwrite,onedrive.appfolder    put as per your requirement (https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#authentication-scopes)

**Swift :**

```
let kMicrosoftApplicationId = "<MicrosoftApplicationId>"
let kMicrosoftRedirectURL = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
let scopesMicroSoft = ["onedrive.readwrite","onedrive.appfolder"] 

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //ONE DRIVE
    ODClient.setMicrosoftAccountAppId(kMicrosoftApplicationId, scopes: scopesMicroSoft)
    return true
}
```

**ViewController  Where you want to login :**

You have to declare the object of ODClient in top

```
import OneDriveSDK

var odClient: ODClient!

func oneDriveClick(sender: UIButton){
    authenticateUser()
}


func authenticateUser(){

    ODClient.clientWithCompletion { (client, error) in
        if ((error == nil)){
            self.odClient = client
            ODClient.setCurrentClient(client)                
            self.getUserDetails()
        }else{
            print("Login error :::: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

func getUserDetails(){

    odClient.drive().request().getWithCompletion { (drive, error) -> Void in
        if(error == nil){
            print("User name : \(drive.owner.user.displayName)")
        }
    }
}
```

**Objective C :**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     [ODClient setMicrosoftAccountAppId: kMicrosoftApplicationId scopes:@[@"onedrive.readwrite",@"onedrive.appfolder"] ];    
   return YES;
}
```

**ViewController Where you want to login :**

**.h code**

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) ODClient *odClient;
```

**.m file code**

```
- (void)oneDriveClick
{
  [self authenticateUser];
}

- (void)authenticateUser{
     [ODClient authenticatedClientWithCompletion:^(ODClient *client, NSError *error){
        if (!error){
          self.odClient = client;
          [ODClient setCurrentClient:client];
          [self getUserDetails];
       }
       else{
          NSLog(@"Error Login :%@",error);
       }
 }];
}

 - (void)getUserDetails{

    [[[self.odClient drive] request] getWithCompletion:^(ODDrive *drive, NSError *error){
        if (!error){
           NSLog(@"User name : %@",drive.owner.user.displayName);
        }        
    }];
  }
```

Enjoy :) (y)

Comment: You have enough rep to leave comments now, please don't use the answer section for this. Thanks.

Comment: @iPhoneDev thanks for your reply, i tried your code on Swift, but i am getting error into this.  We need to declare odClient in starting, but i don't know, which type odClient it is, also in getUserDetails method odClient giving me error for Use of unresolved identifier 'odClient'.                                     & in App Delegate method it will be of return type, but when i return true into this, its showing me white screen. Please help me into this, i am new into swift :)

Comment: @SatyamTayal Hey I updated my answer,  in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions you forgot to put return true which is required which I also forgot to put in my answer. I have update my answer

Comment: @SatyamTayal, I updated the code with objective c also, please check the code and also import the sdk which I have not mentioned in objective c code. :)

Comment: @iPhoneDev Thanks for your help, But the error in this. When i run the application, Clicked on Sign in button, then following error i found---  'We're unable to complete your request' ' Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later'  Please help :)

Comment: @SatyamTayal, did you register the application on developer portal of the oneDrive and that error occurs  may be at that time its server is not reachable. please check, its working and tested code.

Comment: @iPhoneDev Thanks for your reply, I have an admin account of office 365, and i registered on developer portal of the onedrive, and then i created app into this, then i get App id, and i write that app id to project. But the error remains. I followed these steps : - 
https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm  I don't know why this error is coming, when i login into web my id is working, but in this application showing me the above error :(

Comment: @SatyamTayal, Hey as per your comment it look like you Register your app for OneDrive for Business. have you done all your steps in which is mentioned in this sections? and for Azure Active Directory you have to put one line in your **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function put other method of ODClient for Azure :     [ODClient setActiveDirectoryAppId:@"<ActiveDirectoryAppID>"
                          redirectURL:@"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
                                flags:@{@"NoThumbnails" : @(YES)}]; below setMicrosoftAccountAppId method

Comment: There is two  types : 
1.OneDrive
2.OneDrive for Business      I used 1 option for my app

Comment: Actually, i have an account in OneDrive for Buisness, So i am doing for this. I have completed only 5 steps of the link. And I have no AAD account, do i need to make AAD account first, is it necessary? iPhoneDev

Comment: Signup AAD account is free or not?

Comment: @SatyamTayal, you have to add the card details for sign up.  [https://account.windowsazure.com/SignUp]

Comment: @iphoneDev, I am using this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/ Alternative Method, and i found this error : Reply address 'urm:....." specified by the request is not a valid URK. Allowed scehes:'http,https'. which link they are talking about?

Comment: @iPhoneDev Can you plz help me to access one drive files in swift

Comment: @RahulChopra have you tried sample example which is given by OneDrive ? If yes then what an error occurs accessing the files. Please let me know. :)